# Core data Fetch request syntax query

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

List is defined:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *list;

@synthesize list = _list;
```

What is the difference between:

```
list = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

and

```
self.list = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

The first returns all the records in Core Data but the second returns nothing.

Comment: Where is `list` definied?

Comment: I have edited the question to show how list is defined.

Comment: You have a property `self.list`, which is synthesized as instance variable `_list`. But where does the `list` variable come from? - And the RHS of both assignments is identical. It cannot be that they return different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you **MUST** read the App doc about [Encapsulating Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html).

In particular, with the first code snippet you are saying to wrap an instance variable called `_list` through accessor methods.

In general in OOP they are also called setters and getters. A good discussion of pros of them can be found in [Why use getters and setters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters).

So, comments of other people are right. Where does the `list` variable come from?

An important thing you need to understand is that the dot syntax is a a concise way to access method calls. So, for example:

```
NSString *nickname = person.nickname;
person.nickname = @"This is my nickname";
```

is equal to

```
NSString *nickname = [person nickname];
[person setNickname:@"This is my nickname"];
```

A note. Starting form XCode 4.4, the new Apple LLVM compiler 4.0 allows you to skip the `@synthesize` directive. Under the hood the compiler generates an instance variable with a `_` suffix. Further references at [Automatic Property Synthesis With Xcode 4.4](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2012/08/01/property-synthesis-with-xcode-4-dot-4.html).

Comment: I really appreciate the time that you have spent sending me this. I am just learning objective-c and working in a remote area in Ethiopia resources/internet is very difficult to access. Many thanks - I will look into this.